# Unable to find an entry point when calling C++ dll in C#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I am trying to learn P/Invoke, so I created a simple dll in C++

KingFucs.h:

```
namespace KingFuncs
{
    class KingFuncs
    {
    public:
        static __declspec(dllexport) int GiveMeNumber(int i);
    };
}
```

KingFuns.cpp:

```
#include "KingFuncs.h"
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

namespace KingFuncs
{
    int KingFuncs::GiveMeNumber(int i)
    {
        return i;
    }
}
```

So it does compile, then I copied this dll into my WPF's debug folder, with code:

```
[DllImport("KingFuncDll.dll", EntryPoint = "GiveMeNumber", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern int GiveMeNumber(
              int i
              );
```

And calling it in button click:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int num = GiveMeNumber(123);
}
```

But it gives me exception:

> Unable to find an entry point named 'GiveMeNumber' in DLL
>   'KingFuncDll.dll'.

Really.... what have I done wrong... It obviously able to find the DLL, otherwise would be another exception.  But my method name is exactly the same.... I can't think of other reason.

Comment: Please see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849541/writing-c-intended-to-be-called-from-c

Comment: I solved same question, and describe it at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45263176/1817569).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to use `extern "C"` when you export your function so that you suppress C++ name mangling. And you also should not try to p/invoke to members of a class. Use free functions instead:

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) int GiveMeNumber(int i)
    {
        return i;
    }
}
```

On the managed side your `DllImport` attribute is all wrong. Don't use `SetLastError` which is for Win32 APIs only. Don't bother setting `CharSet` if there are not text parameters. No need for `ExactSpelling`. And the calling convention is presumably `Cdecl`.

```
[DllImport("KingFuncDll.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int GiveMeNumber(int i);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But it is not possible to call a function of a class? (This is my first time using extern "C", I thought I always need to define function within class in C++)

Comment: You do not need to define a function within a class in C++. Old fashioned C functions are just fine.

Comment: Shall this extern "C"{} also be applied to structs?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are declaring the C++ "function" inside a C++ class and are telling P/Invoke  to use StdCall.

Try to declare a C++ function outside a class and and export it like you did. Then your code should work.

If you really must have a C++ function inside a class, take a look at CallingConvention.ThisCall. But then you are responsible for creating your unmanaged class instance and pass it as the first parameter of your P/Invoke call

Answer (score 0):

The entry point name of a dll file is given in .exp file which is found in debug folder where other source files are present. If dumpbin doesn't work you can try this.