# The name '$exception' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, exception, visual-studio-2012

Today I was debugging an application in my work. I proceeded to set a breakpoint in one of my catch blocks in order to inspect an exception with more detail.

The `View Detail` modal window opens normally, but instead of showing me the details of the exception, it is throwing a strange error, one I never got, nor I know what it means:

[image: View Details Exception]

The error says:

> The name '$exception' does not exist in the current context

This is frustating because I am within the catch block scope, so I should be able to see my exception.

After restarting my application, I managed to debug it just fine. This was the only time (so far) I got this error.

Does anyone know what it means and how can I fix it (without having to restart application)?

**NOTE**: I am using **Visual Studio 2012 Premium**. Version **11.0.61030.00 Update 4**

Comment: $exception looks like something in javascript, c# would not have the $ in front of it, can you verify that your JS files aren't the ones throwing the error?

Comment: @RonBeyer This application does not handle JS at all. It is entirely written in C#, and you can also see that the exception type is `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException` which is a .NET exception

Comment: `$exception` is debugger magic for "the current exception". Sometimes some bits are flipped for no reason and the debugger stops working, it happens.

Comment: @CodeCaster Actually, I restarted the program and it just worked fine this time. However, restarting the application takes some time, and getting to this catch block takes even more. I was looking for a solution on how to fix this without restarting VS or my application, if I find myself in this situation in the future.

Comment: If you haven't got a memory dump and don't have steps to reproduce it, I'm afraid there's very little chance you'll get a satisfying answer. I've seen errors like this pop up once in every few years; shrug it off and continue working. ;)

Comment: @RonBeyer, C#6 introduced $ :) Check Interpolated Strings.

Comment: @usefulBee Yes, but it would not appear in an error message like that since it is compile-time transformed into a `string.Format` call. Exceptions are runtime, so by the time the exception is raised, the string no longer contains the $.

Comment: I got this error when I imported `DLL` with wrong calling convention.

Answer (score 2):

Try explicitly to tell the compiler how to import the dll. Ex:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace BitmapProcessingCs
{
    public static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("BitmapProcessingCpp.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void GenerateBitmap(IntPtr src, int dimension);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem in these steps:
**step 1)** If you program your custom DLL in C++ using Visual studio,then at the property page of your project set the `Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)`parameter to `Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)`. 
**step 2)** To function deceleration in `.h` file use `__declspec(dllexport)` keyword like below:

```
__declspec(dllexport) double Sub(int a,int b);
```

**step 3)** Build and export DLL file, then use the **Dependency Walker** software to get your function **EntryPoint**.

**step4)** Import DLL file In the C# project and set **EntryPoint** and **CallingConvention** variable like below:

```
[DllImport("custom.dll", EntryPoint = "?Sub@@Y234NN@Z", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

    public static extern double Sub(int a,int b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at MSDN's library : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164891.aspx

According to them, you'll get an exception if you try to evaluate an exception object if no exception has occurred. But, since you're in the catch block, an excption has occurred... Without seeing your code it's hard to guess, but is it maybe possible that you have multiple threads running, and the exception was consumed by one thread before being handled by another? Doesn't really make sense but it's worth looking at.
A safe(r) option would be to ensure you check if the exception is null in your logger, before trying to get detail from it.
Also worth looking at: The HttpRequestException contains an inner exception, which might be the source of your null reference? Just speculating.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with trapsuutjies, there is probably no exception. To suppress this error, press Ctrl+Alt+E, expand Managed Debugging Assistant, and uncheck LoadFromContext.

Answer (score 0):

When I saw this error, I was also getting 'Could not evaluate expression' errors in the debugger. That lead me to this post by Rick Strahl that said it was a bug in the original version of Visual Studio 2013.

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Nov/21/Visual-Studio-2013-Could-not-evaluate-Expression-Debugger-Abnormality

When I checked the machine I was on, it in fact had VS2013 without any of the updates installed. Installing the updates fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got this when in Configuration Manager the Configuration for the project was set to Release. Switching to debug solve this.